# Proper usage of try/catch block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a try/catch block that I have written into the JetBrains Webstorm IDE that is giving me an error.  The error reads as follows: "'throw' of exception caught locally / This inspection reports any instances of JavaScript **throw** statements whose exceptions are always caught by containing **try** statements.  Using **throw** statements as a 'goto' to change the local flow of control is likely to be confusing."

```
try {
    var invoice = parseInt(localStorage[0]);
    if (isNaN(invoice)) {
        console.warn("invoice NaN; let's fix that...");
        throw "executing catch";
    }
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.test();
    invoice = 1;
}
finally {
    localStorage[invoice] = JSON.stringify(Ticket);
    console.log("localStorage[" + invoice + '] : ' + localStorage[invoice]);
    localStorage[0] = parseInt(localStorage[0]) + 1;
}
```

If I place the activity from the catch block into the if block of the try block, then i will have no need of try/catch/finally.  So how else would you throw an error other than with a conditional statement (if), and how can you avoid using throw as a "goto"?

Thanks!

Comment: `try/catch` is usually used when there's a call to a function in the `try` block, and the exception may be thrown by the function.

Comment: Personally, this approach does not bother me.  Sometimes this kind of structure makes the most sense, and I don't find it confusing at all.  It's particularly useful if you might need to throw from multiple different points inside of the `try` block.  If you only need to throw from one then the `catch` block can be a bit redundant, unless you expect some other function call to throw as well.

Comment: You usually don't *manually* call `throw`.  `try`/`catch` is generally used when a function you are calling might "throw" an error and you want to "catch" it.

Comment: If you agree with @cdhowie you can simply disable this warning in Preferences. It's `Inspections -> Javascript -> Error Handling -> Exception used for local control-flow`

Comment: Why are you throwing an error?  Why do you think that's desirable over putting the catch code in the if block?  The try/finally still serves its purpose even without the throw and catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functions identically and is much cleaner.  Why throw/catch?

```
try {
    var invoice = parseInt(localStorage[0]);
    if(isNaN(invoice)){
        console.warn("invoice NaN; let's fix that...");
        console.log("executing catch");   // not really needed
        this.test();
        invoice = 1;
    }
} finally {
    localStorage[invoice] = JSON.stringify(Ticket);
    console.log("localStorage[" + invoice + '] : ' + localStorage[invoice]);
    localStorage[0] = parseInt(localStorage[0]) + 1;
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, you probably don't need the try/finally at all, unless this.test() throws errors.

Comment: Note that in more complex scenarios you may have multiple `throw` statements; using a try/catch block allows you to centralize the error handling code.  If you only have one `throw` (and no functions you call can throw) then there is indeed little point in using try/catch in this way.

Comment: Can you have a `try` without a `catch`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat You must have at least one of `catch` or `finally`.  If you only have a `finally` block and an error occurs, the `finally` block will run and then the error will be propagated up the call stack.  This construct allows you to clean up after an error, but not catch the error.

Comment: Okay, so I'm ditching the try/catch for this scenario ;-p  I appreciate all the thoughts about this matter.  I now understand try/catch/finally more completely.